# Reducing a collection of lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I have a vector of lambdas:

```
public interface MyLambda {
    int execute(Object lambdaParams);
}

Vector<MyLambda> lambdas = new Vector<>();
lambdas.add((params) -> {return 1});
lambdas.add((params) -> {return 2});
lambdas.add((params) -> {return 3});
```

I want to call all lambdas with the same parameters, and sum up the results. I tried something along the lines of:

```
int sum = lambdas.parallelStream().collect(Math::addExact);
```

or:

```
int sum = lambdas.parallelStream().reduce(0, Math::addExact);
```

But naturally it didn't work. I've used a more traditional approach:

```
  int sum = 0;
  for (MyLambda lambda : lambdas) {
     sum += lambda.execute(myParams);
  }
```

And it worked, but it feels like the wrong way.

How can I execute all lambdas and sum the results?

Comment: Instead of getting the property, your `mapToInt` would simply receive a `ToIntFunction` that invokes the `MyLambda`'s `execute method.

Comment: `lambdas.parallelStream().mapToInt(l -> l.execute(myParams)).sum();` or something like that, maybe.

Comment: `(params) -> {return 1;}`, `(params) -> {return 2;}`, etc. are verbose variants of `params -> 1`, `params -> 2`, etc. You may evaluate them with `lambdas.stream().mapToInt(my -> my.execute(myParams)).sum()` or `lambdas.stream().mapToInt(my -> my.execute(myParams)) .reduce(Math::addExact)`, if you prefer. By the way, `Vector` has been superseded by `ArrayList` twenty years ago…

Comment: Well, as you might suspect, I haven't really used Java for a long, long time...